# How can I get the same Singleton by parameter with Kotlin ？

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to get the same Singleton of a class

I can use Code A do that,  you know that  LessOtherState.getInstance1(context) always get the same Singleton instance1, and  LessOtherState.getInstances(context) always get the same Singleton instances...

But Code A  is not good, how can I  optimize it?

In my mind , I hope `LessOtherState.getInstances(context,1)` always get a same Singleton of the class, and `LessOtherState.getInstances(context,2)` always get a same Singleton of the class too.

**Code A**

```
class LessOtherState  private constructor(context: Context) {

    var openDeleteDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    fun set_openDeleteDialog(isShow:Boolean) {
        openDeleteDialog = isShow
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance1: LessOtherState ? = null

        @Volatile private var instance2: LessOtherState ? = null

        @Volatile private var instance3: LessOtherState ? = null

        // Singleton
        fun getInstance1(context: Context): LessOtherState {
            return instance1 ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance1 ?: LessOtherState (context).also { instance1=it }
            }
        }

        // Singleton
        fun getInstance2(context: Context): LessOtherState {
            return instance2 ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance2 ?: LessOtherState (context).also { instance2=it }
            }
        }

        // Singleton
        fun getInstance3(context: Context): LessOtherState {
            return instance3 ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance3 ?: LessOtherState (context).also { instance3=it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Added Content**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

At present, the following code modified by ChatGPT works.

**Code B**

```
companion object {
        private val instanceMap = ConcurrentHashMap<EDialogbox, EditDialogState>()

        fun getInstances(context: Context, key: EDialogbox): EditDialogState {
            return instanceMap.computeIfAbsent(key) {
                EditDialogState(context)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have 3 instances of LessOtherState, it is by definition NOT a singleton.  A singleton only has 1 instance, ever.  This is just a global value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not singletons, since you have more than one instance. They are lazily-loaded instances.

The quick and easy solution is to make your three functions private, and then make a function that calls through to them:

```
fun getInstances(context: Context, instanceNumber: Int) = when (instanceNumber) {
     1 -> getInstance1(context)
     2 -> getInstance2(context)
     3 -> getInstance3(context)
     else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("$instanceNumber is invalid")
}
```

If you want to avoid all that code repetition, you can instead use a ConcurrentHashMap to store your items.

```
companion object {
    private val instanceMap = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, LessOtherState>()
   
    fun getInstances(context: Context, instanceNumber: Int): LessOtherState {
        check(instanceNumber in 1..3) { "$instanceNumber is invalid" }
        return instanceMap.computeIfAbsent(instanceNumber) { LessOtherState(context.applicationContext) }
    }
}
```

The downside here is that ConcurrentHashMap is a Java class and therefore `computeIfAbsent` is not inline, so a lambda function will be created every time this function is called. If you wanted to avoid that tiny overhead, you could create a Context property as well.

```
companion object {
    private val context: Context? = null?
    private val instanceMap = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, LessOtherState>()
    private val instantiater = Function<Int, _> { LessOtherState(context!!) }

    fun getInstances(context: Context, instanceNumber: Int): LessOtherState {
        check(instanceNumber in 1..3) { "$instanceNumber is invalid" }
        this.context = context.applicationContext
        return instanceMap.computeIfAbsent(instanceNumber, instantiator)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code `private val instantiator = java.util.function.Function<Int, _> { LessOtherState(context) }
    ` can not be compiled.

Comment: Thanks! Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1 with Koltin 1.8.10

Comment: Would you please see my added content in the quetsion?

Comment: Thanks!   you can see the image for error  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m49w4no9vefcxkz/error.png?dl=0

Comment: It seems that  `private val instantiator = java.util.function.Function<Int, _> { LessOtherState(context) }` doesn't accept the parameter `context`,  I don't know why.

Comment: Oh of course, because `context` is a parameter of the function, not a property of the companion object. See update.

Answer (score 0):

use

> by lazy

The LazyImpl have DCL will make sure the object is Singleton too

Comment: Thanks! I need return to different Singleton

Comment: In my mind , I hope `LessOtherState.getInstances(context,1)` always get a same Singleton of the class, and `LessOtherState.getInstances(context,2)` always get a same Singleton of the class too.